# firebase storage can not upload any file

Tags: firebase, storage

When I try to upload any image files to Firebase Storage, I got a wrong message.

```
Object { code_: "storage/unauthorized", message_: "Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access 'img/product/1540281542536/58916.jpg'.", serverResponse_: "{\n  \"error\": {\n    \"code\": 403,\n    \"message\": \"Permission denied. Could not perform this operation\"\n  }\n}", name_: "FirebaseError" }
```

I don't know why it can not work

here is my Storage Rule

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      match /img {
        match /{allImages=**} {
            allow read
        }
        match /product/{productID}/{imageId} {
            allow create, write, delete: if request.auth != null
        }
      }
      match /user/{userId} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my upload code

```
$formImgUpload.on('change', function (e) {
  let file = this.files[0]
  let rootRef = firebase.storage().ref()
  let fileName = 'img/product/' + id + '/' + file.name
  let fileRef = rootRef.child(fileName)

  fileRef.put(file).then(function (result) {
    console.log('"' + fileName + '" was uploaded successfully.')

    result.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {
      $img.attr('src', url)
      $fileUrl.text(url)
    })
  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err)
  })
})
```

can someone help me how to write correct rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem too. Are you uploading from your client? If so, at the moment you aren't sending anything for the request.auth so it will always be null.

To fix this, send a custom token --> https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

Create custom tokens using the Firebase Admin SDK is quite an easy way, send in a token from the server using your UID and then authenticate that at the client. Then when you send your data to Storage the request.auth goes with it and the database rules will then be able to handle the situation.

Hopefully, that helps.

All the best.